# When we need attr_accessor in our rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can anyone please explain why we need attr_accessor in our rails application(Real scenario when we actually need it)? How it is going to helpful in our application inspite of fact that its existence is temporary?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not Google. There are plenty of resources for this online. The Rails Documentation is just one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you're new to programming in general as said above, here is a detailed, but yet aimed to be simple explanation.

Ruby is one of many languages that follows the [object oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) paradigm (OOP). So let's say that you are developing a system to manage products from a store and you want to represent these real world products in your code. You can achieve this by using a [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)), which will contain **actions** that your real world product can perform and **qualities** that it has. Let's assume your product is a TV.

The **actions** are defined in OOP with [methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)). What can you perform with a TV? You can turn it on, turn it of, increase or decrease the volume and set the currrent channel.

```
Television
|-> TurnOn
|-> TurnOff
|-> IncreaseVolume
|-> DecreaseVolume
|-> SetChannel
```

The **qualities** are defined in OOP with [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(programming)) and they can make each of your representations, that are called [instances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_(computer_science)), unique. What are some qualities of the TV? Its state (ON or OFF), its current channel and its current volume. Below, a possible set of TV properties.

```
Television
|-> State => ON
|-> Channel => 9
|-> Volume => 50
```

Awesome, right? So you have a television class, that contains some operations that it can perform and some properties that represents its current state. Let's say now that you want to use your brand new television. You need to know if it is already on or off, in which channel it is and what volume is set. Several languages implement it in several ways, but let's keep our focus on Ruby, shall we?

A ruby class can expose its properties in three ways, with [accessors](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor), [readers](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader) and [writers](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-attr_writer). With accessors, you can both **read** and **write** values, with readers you can **read** and with writers you can **write**. Why is this important anyways? In OOP you have this concept of [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) where you should only expose what is needed and with the needed access, to avoid, for instance, someone to make your TV current volume jumping from 50 to 100 in a single operation, while the TV should increase it or decrease it by 1. So you should only expose to the consumer of your classes, the properties and operations in a way that doesn't hurt the way it should work (business rules).

Take a deep look at these concepts and you'll probably be good to go and better understand ruby accessors, it's just a syntax to provide access to your object state with read and write permissions from outside of your class ;)

Comment: Thanks alot for sharing your valuable knowledge!!!!.

Comment: That's allright @NamitSrivastava, if I wasn't clear in my explanation or there is still any question, please let me know! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* `attr_accessor`. `attr_accessor` is a convenience method. It's there to save you time. If you don't care about saving time, then don't use it.

Let's take a look.

If you fire up your console and define a class

```
> class Foo
>   
> end
```

And create a new `Foo` like this:

```
> foo = Foo.new
 => #<Foo:0x00000008f2b9a0>
```

You'll find that foo responds to neither `bar=` (a `setter`) nor `bar` a `getter`):

```
> foo.bar = :baz
NoMethodError: undefined method `bar=' for #<Foo:0x00000008f2b9a0>

> foo.bar
NoMethodError: undefined method `bar' for #<Foo:0x00000008f2b9a0>
```

Or, you could define `Foo` like this:

```
> class Foo
>   
>   def bar=(val)
>     @bar = val
>   end
> 
>   def bar
>     @bar
>   end
>   
> end

> foo = Foo.new
 => #<Foo:0x00000004b6dec0> 

> foo.bar = :baz
 => :baz 

> foo.bar
 => :baz
```

In which case, `foo` now responds to `bar=` and `bar`.

Alternatively, you can simply do:

```
> class Foo
>   attr_accessor :bar
>   
> end

> foo = Foo.new
 => #<Foo:0x00000005192bc0> 

> foo.bar = :baz
 => :baz 

> foo.bar
 => :baz
```

So, would you *really* prefer to define all your own getters and setters? Or, just use `attr_accessor`?

Comment: I guess, the underlying question is why would we want to use transient accessors in active models?

Comment: Hi Jvillian, actually I am new to ruby and programming in general. So, I just want to know reason behind this getter and setter method stuff?

Let us say we use puts "Hello world" to display output Hello World. So, in the same manner why we need to set and read as below mentioned manner

> foo.bar = :baz
 => :baz

Comment: Why would you use setters and getters? That is a *very* basic question. I do not believe SO is intended to be a tutoring site. There are many resources available to you on the web. I suggest you start with those.